# Node.js - detect rename file/directory event

Tags: node.js, fs, file-rename, chokidar

I need to detect rename event of a particular file/directory. I am using [chokidar](https://github.com/paulmillr/chokidar) - this one triggers `unlink` and `add` events, thus it is not possible to use it.

I also tried `fs.watch` - this one triggers two `rename` events, but unfortunately first one contains original name and the second one contains new name - this approach makes it unreliable in case many renames are triggered at the same time.

Snippet of fs.watch I use:

```
fs.watch(folder, function (event, filename) {
    console.log('event: ' + event);
    console.log('filename: ' + filename);
});
```

Is there any reliable way (ideally one rename event which has 2 arguments - original name and new name) in Node.js to detect file/directory rename?

Comment: Can we see how you are using `fs.watch`?

Comment: @MaxBaldwin: added snippet of fs.watch I use.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: yes. Use nsfw (node sentinel file watcher) - https://blog.axosoft.com/nsfw/